# phpspread convert to PDF has no headers text color

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

when spreadsheet(xlsx) convert to PDF , header's text looks like does not have color,
Its color must be "no white".

my steps..

1. $this->sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('&L&K000000 left text &R page number &P / &N");
2. save xlsx
3. convert to pdf ( soffice command )

step2) xlsx have header's color ,looks like fine.
but, step3) pdf has no header's color ( text color is white , &K000000 does not work.. )

version of does not work
phpspread:1.29.0
Libreoffice:7.2.7.2

old version , header's text color default is 000000, so after convert pdf looks like works fine.
version of works fine
phpspread:1.9.0
LibreOffice:5.3.6.1